# How to pass user information into each statement rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

So I'm currently trying to pass user information into an `each` statement within rails so I can display the album users info

Here's what I have so far

index.html.erb

```rb
<main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-5">Albums</h1>
    <p class="lead">Here we show all albums and it's details</p>

    <div class="row">
      <% @albums.each do |album| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%# image_tag(@albumImage ['thumbnailUrl']) %>
          <h5 class="card-title">
            <%= album['title'] %>
          </h5>

          <p>By: <%= album.user['userId'] %><p>
          <%= link_to "View Album", album_path(album['id']), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= will_paginate @albums, renderer: WillPaginate::ActionView::BootstrapLinkRenderer, class: 'margin-auto' %>
</main>
```

album.rb

```rb
class Album < ApplicationRecord
  include HTTParty

  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :albums
end
```

album_controller.rb

```
require 'will_paginate/array'

class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @albums = HTTParty
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums', :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
      .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

    @user = HTTParty
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + params[:id], :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
  end

  def show
    @album = HTTParty
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/' + params[:id], :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

    @albumPhotos = HTTParty
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?album=' + params[:id], :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
      .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

    @user = HTTParty
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + params[:id], :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
  end
end
```

I'm grabbing all info from API's, no database data. Obviously, I'm trying to grab the user data to place it into the `each` but I also want to make sure that the `userID` matches in the album show as well so it displays the right user information

Comment: can you please elaborate more didn't get what is your question

Comment: I'm not sure how more I could elaborate, I'm trying to add the user information into the `each` statement in the index `<p>By: <%= album.user['userId'] %><p>`

Comment: If I get correctly you can directly do it like this way `album.user.id` you will get the id of that user

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the user details to the album by looping through or please update your API get response combining both user and album.

For now,

```
class AlbumsController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @albums = HTTParty.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums', :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)

      @user = HTTParty.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

      @albums.each do |album|
        user = @users.first{|u| u if u.id == album.userId }
        album.merge!({name: user.name, email: user.email})  if user.present?
      end
  end
end
```

Based on this you can display correct user info based your condition I have added if user email is present check,

```
<% @albums.each do |album| %>
    <% if album["email"].present? %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <%# image_tag(@albumImage ['thumbnailUrl']) %>
          <h5 class="card-title">
            <%= album['title'] %>
          </h5>

          <p>By: <%= album.user['userId'] %><p>
          <%= link_to "View Album", album_path(album['id']), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
     <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Where does the first block of code go? How would I go about combine the response there separate urls?

Comment: @B.J.B Please find the updated answer.  If API is maintained by you then you can customize your API response by combining the back end data query

Comment: All requests are coming from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com`but I'll take a look at the updated response

Comment: If you don't have permission to customize then please go for above answer

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error https://i.gyazo.com/82000ff3dca3f517f8cd853952938018.png

Comment: Updated the answer @B.J.B

Comment: OK now I'm getting https://i.gyazo.com/09172ffcde8b2d0a6ab27b1dec38cccd.png

Comment: Please debug it, we can’t answer every issue here.